# Does Active Directory have a Northwind equivalent?

Tags: active-directory

I want to develop a AD app, but I don't have an actual Active Directory.
Just as SQL ships with Northwind sample DB, is there such a thing Active Directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While there is no sample AD file/db for you to use you could easily set something up using a trial of Windows Server.

You can download a VHD from [Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/evaluate-windows-server-2016) and setup a test domain.  Create a few users and different OUs (or whatever else you need for your app) and you're off to the races.

***Update***: Microsoft has changed things up since this original answer.  You can download a VHD of Server 2012 R2 from the updated link, but for newer Server editions you'll need to download the ISO and install or sign up for an Azure account and use a pre-built image.  They also have virtual labs but those are focused on running through some task.

Comment: This link is now dead but [wayback machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20150402180856/http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=16572) reveals it was the download for "Windows Server 2008 R2 Evaluation Virtual Hard Drive Images for Hyper-V (180 Days)"

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I updated the link and commented above.